# create archetype of multi module mvn project

Tags: maven, archetypes

I'm trying to grab my multi module project and generate an Archetype from it via :

archetype:create-from-project

The thing is, that my project not change groupid of modules.
when i generate project from this archetype my new project changes only "package" declarations at the top of class...it doesn't change directory name(it use previous groupid).

Comment: hi @mhaller can we create archetype of multi module projects.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the following [article](http://intellectualcramps.wordpress.com/2011/04/15/maven-archetype-creation-tips/) that lights up the maven archetype generation and even points to example filesets